# What gentoo stage should I install for Xeon processor?

Tags: linux, gentoo

I own Quad CPU `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7450  @ 2.40GHz`
What gentoo stage3 should I install? Seems `ia64` and `amd64` are not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The Xeon is an amd64 (aka x86_64) architecture.

Comment: yeah. I was wrong. Seems `amd64` profile works.